# Is it considered a loss if you logout or close the game during the countdown?

Tags: starcraft-2

You search for a game on Battle.net, the countdown starts and at the same moment your telephone also starts ringing. Suppose you want to take that call.

Is it considered a loss if you logout or close the game before the actual game begins?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

According to the patch notes released today:

> A player who logs out of the game during a match countdown now receives a point loss. The other player now receives a message that the opposing player has canceled the queue and neither receives a point bonus nor penalty.

So yes, you will take the loss by closing out/quitting the game.

Source: http://us.battle.net/sc2/en/forum/topic/5271506462?page=1

Answer (score 4):

Yeah, it ends up in a loss.
[Here's Destiny raging about it.](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ltXVC0XkHkw)

Comment: Don't think you can answer an "x or y" question with "yes", but at least the video makes it clear :D

Comment: @Fadeway - The answer to both parts of the question is `Yes` so how can any other answer be correct?

Comment: @Fadeway in a logical sense "Do you want an apple or an orange", "Yes" is a perfectly valid response. People who do too much computer programming would even suggest the correct response!

Comment: @Ramhound my comment addresses an older state of the question; it has since been edited.

Answer (score 1):

**This answer is now (with Patch 1.5) outdated.**

If you manage to **logout** in time you will get a **tie**, as shown in the picture below. I guess if your computer freezes or you try to Alt F4 you might get a loss. The following reasons might apply:

- Killing a process with Alt F4 is not instant. Every process is given some time to shut down properly. As you only have 3 seconds before the game starts, this might not be enough. Especially on slow or otherwise occupied computers.
- Exiting Starcraft with Alt F4 might not send a proper logout signal to the sever. Which means you are considered online for a short timeout period.

[image]

Comment: Why go to the effort of saying an answer is outdated instead of simply updating the answer?

Comment: Sorean has posted the correct answer. I want to archive my answer. That is why.